# Is it safe to drink dark tea dating to 1970?

Tags: tea

The tea has been saved in a glass bottle with metal top, stored in dark kitchen cabinet all these years.

Answer (score 1):

Safe probably yes, you will use boiling water (or as close to boiling water).

Will it be good ? maybe.

It will probably taste stale,